# Nodejs - Postgres - Notify - Error bind message

Tags: node.js, postgresql, notify, node-postgres

I am using [node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries) (v-6.1.2)

This is code I am refactoring because of un-parameterized params in the query. This is code I did not write!

I have the following function `publish`, where `pubClient` is the result of

```
new pg.Client(pubsubUri).connect((err, client) => {
    if(err) return logger.error('database-connect', err.message)

    pubClient = client
})
```

When I run `publish` I get the following error:

`error: bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0`

This is my publish method: (type and message are both of type string)

```
let publish = ( type, message) => {
    if (pubClient) {
        pubClient.query('NOTIFY "$1", \'$2\'', [type, message], (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
              return
            }
          return true
        })

    }

    return false
}
```

I can't figure out what the correct syntax is for the query or why I am getting this error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How are you calling `publish`?

Comment: Also you're returning `true` and `false` incorrectly. This is asynchronous programming and you need to callback with `true` or `false`

Comment: I know. This is code I'm refactoring (which I did not write). It was actually being run synchronously. I simply added the callback to see what the error was

Comment: As is `publish` is being called as `publish('HELLO', {"payload": {....}})`

Comment: It must be the query string that's messed up. It looks odd as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NOTIFY channel [ , payload ]
```

channel can not be parameterized. Try using pg_notify:

```
let publish = (type, message) => {
    if (pubClient) {
        pubClient.query('SELECT pg_notify($1, $2)', [type, message], (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
              return
            }
          return true
        })

    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks! Where in the docs does it say channel cannot be parameterised?

Comment: It does not say in the docs. But you can see from sample query `NOTIFY test, 'test';` first parameter is not a string, but rather an identifier, and thus can not be bound. Same thing happens with table names - you can't bind them.

pg_listen should work.